# Plotting with a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

The thing is i have a matrix and when i use imagesc() it goes like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CesoA.png) but my goal is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Grj.png).
So my question is does any one know which plot is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCo9B.png) or some one has document about this, thanks.

Comment: Judging from the two images, maybe your data is in polar coordinates `(imagesc` uses Cartesian coordinates). Also, the goal image seems to use the `jet` colormap

Comment: Yes, i spent last 5 days trying to wrote in polar coordinate but it fail.
And now i'm in stress with polar plot.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two vectors `r` and `theta` that give the polar coordinates, or two matrices `rGrid` and `thetaGrid` that give the polar coordinates for each element of the data matrix, then code like this will work:

```
r=linspace(1,20,20);
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,20);

data = r'.*sin(2.*theta); % INSERT DATA HERE

[thetaGrid,rGrid]=meshgrid(theta,r); % Create coordinate grid if needed
[xGrid,yGrid]=pol2cart(thetaGrid,rGrid);

surf(xGrid,yGrid,data); % Plot data
view(2);
```

[image: Polar plot]

Just keep in mind that the rows of the data matrix need to correspond to different radii, and columns need to correspond to different values of theta. If it's flipped, then transpose the matrix before plotting:

```
data = data';
```

Also, if the data doesn't wrap around from 0 to 2*pi radians, then repeat the first value of theta as the last value, and repeat the first column of the data matrix as a new final column:

```
theta(end+1)=theta(1);
data=cat(2,data,data(:,1));
```

There is also a 3D Polar Plot function on the MATLAB file exchange, but I do not have any experience using it: [3D Polar Plot](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13200-3d-polar-plot)